# Perform an os.walk through a zip compressed file using the zipfile module

Tags: python-3.x, zip, os.walk

I would like to do an os.walk through a zipped file without extracting files. The zipfile module can provide the information needed. Does anyone have a script that will output the same list of tuples that os.walk outputs when looking through an uncompressed directory tree?

I have a partial solution. This only goes one level deep and outputs to a dictionary which can easily be converted to os.walk() output format:

```
import zipfile

def zipwalk(zfile):
    dlistdb = {'' : []}
    for info in zfile.infolist():
        ilist = info.filename.split('/')
        if '' in ilist:
            ilist.remove('')
        if info.is_dir():
            dlistdb[ilist[-1]] = []
        elif ilist[-2] in dlistdb:
            dlistdb[ilist[-2]].append(ilist[-1])
        else:
            dlistdb[''].append(ilist[-1])

    return dlistdb
```

Answer (score 4):

Answered my own question. Here's the code I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os
import zipfile

# Mimic os.walk() function for zipfiles
def zipwalk(zfile):
    # Initialize database
    dlistdb = {}

    # Walk through zip file information list
    for info in zfile.infolist():
        if info.is_dir():
            zpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(info.filename).rstrip('/'))
            zfile = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(info.filename).rstrip('/'))
            if zpath in dlistdb:
                dlistdb[zpath][0].append(zfile)
            else:
                dlistdb[zpath] = [[zfile], []]
        else:
            zpath = os.path.dirname(info.filename)
            zfile = os.path.basename(info.filename)
            if zpath in dlistdb:
                dlistdb[zpath][1].append(zfile)
            else:
                dlistdb[zpath] = [[], [zfile]]

    # Convert to os.walk() output format
    dlist = []
    for key in dlistdb.keys():
        dlist.append((key, dlistdb[key][0], dlistdb[key][1]))

    return iter(dlist)

zfile = zipfile.ZipFile('data/test.zip')
db = zipwalk(zfile)

print(list(db))
```

Comment: Thanks for coming back and showing your own answer!